# Crack 4 digit password using putty or VT100 Emulator

Tags: passwords, putty, vt100

Okay, so I have a hardware device that I have to connect to using putty. The device is protected by a 4 digit password. So I know there are 10,000 combinations and I know the device takes 5 seconds between each wrong password. So it'll take approx. 13 hours to complete.

TL;DR

How can I enter every combination into a putty window? I was thinking like a macro of some sort. Because the device I'm connecting to is like a hyper-terminal vt100 connection.

Update: When I connect to the device, I can interface with some things. But when I press 'E'
to edit the MAP on the device. it tells me to enter the 4 digit password.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but: PuTTY suggests Windows, and Windows supports other freeware SSH clients as well. Such as Cygwin, which opens up a world of scripting. Any reason why you specifically want PuTTY?

Comment: It's the only way I know how to connect to this device :-( 

It uses HyperTerminal or a VT100 emulator.

Comment: Ok, so not necessarily PuTTY then. What about some other emulator that allows for scripting itself? Or, in the old days, many terminal programs allowed for reading a file with commands, to set the connection details et al, or to fetch data. Such command files might not allow for true scripting (such as writing loops). But generating a single (but huge) command file with all 10,000 possibilities might be much easier than trying to script PuTTY?

Comment: Aha, your question actually mentioned that VT100; I totally missed that, and so did others given the answers. When people see PuTTY, they think SSH, I guess. Why not remove PuTTY from the question...?

Comment: Yea, that makes sense. I went the single huge file route using autohotkey http://pastebin.ca/1938488

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help. This is interfacing ssh using python. http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/6618/1/
Shouldn't be difficult to learn if you know python. You can do it on cygwin.

How could i have forgotten expect???? Use autoexpect to generate a script and then use some scripting lanaguage to substitue different passwords and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

[Tera Term Pro](http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA002416/teraterm.html) is a terminal emulator that can connect to a serial port and has a macro language.

In Tera Term Pro, go to **Help** → **Index** → **MACRO help** to read about the macro language. Look at the example macro files (.ttl files) for examples.

Here's an example macro to get you started. Save the following text into a file named `pinsearch.ttl`. To start the macro, go to **Control** → **Macro** and open the `pinsearch.ttl` file. To pause or stop the macro, click on the MACRO window and use the Pause or End buttons.

```
for i 0 9999

  int2str i_text i
  strlen i_text
  len = result

  if len=1 then
    pin_text = "000"
  elseif len=2 then
    pin_text = "00"
  elseif len=3 then
    pin_text = "0"
  else
    pin_text = ""
  endif

  strconcat pin_text i_text

  send "E"
  wait "password?"

  send pin_text
  wait "ok" "wrong"

  if result=1 goto found_it

  wait "command?"

next

messagebox "Didn't find password" ""
end

:found_it
messagebox pin_text ""
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can likely accomplish this by writing an autohotkey script. Or, if you know another scripting language, write a  bruteforcer in that. You may also be able to find some premade ssh bruteforcing tool somewhere that will let you define the keyspace as 4 char passwords, all digits.

Comment: I wast thinking this also. But I'm in no position to begin reading about writing a brute force script. 

I have found a couple of options but nothing to just simply enter 0000-9999 into a window, wait 5 seconds in between, and move to the next.

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge list of of password cracking tools at **sectools.org/crackers.html**

As for your situation, I suggest using **THC Hydra** (#3 on the sectools' list) which you can download from http://freeworld.thc.org/thc-hydra/

Comment: Hydra looked promising but the option i select for putty which is "serial" .